# Is it correct to say "four hours French" in this context?

Tags: phrase-request

Is it better to say:

> "French pupils have **four hours French** in a week"

or:

> "French pupils have **four hours' French** in a week"

or:

> "French pupils have **four hours of French** in a week"

to speak about their timetable?

Comment: Please read through our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) on meta for some useful tips about asking and formatting questions, providing details and writing good titles, saying "thanks", etc. The community will quickly tire of a long series of questions that ask little more than "Which one is right?" with nothing but a "Thank you" at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Sticklers for grammar may insist on "four hours **of** French", or if they're really pernickety<sup>1</sup> they might insist on "four hours **of** French **lessons**" or "four hours **of lessons in** French".

In spoken English, there's absolutely nothing weird or objectionable about just saying "four hours French". In written English, I would include the **of**, as long as the audience was people who know how people talk about school timetables. It's likely the audience will include people who are at least a little fussy.

There's no need for a genitive apostrophe in any of those options.

---

<sup>1</sup>: American English speakers apparently say *persnickety* instead. Ain't dialects grand? For those unfamiliar, the word means overly concerned with minor or trivial details.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out why, but I find that whereas it seems perfectly idiomatic for a pupil to say *We have two hours free study time on Friday afternoons* with no preposition, I'm ***very much*** more inclined to include it in the singular version *We have **an hour of** free study time on Friday afternoons*. I only wish I could think of a specific "contrasting pair" along these lines that might be common enough to check out on Google Books (even if only to discover whether I'm simply *imagining* a difference in preference there! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I would say "an hour of free study time", too. Or "an hour's free study time". It would hardly be the only things that behaves oddly, in actual usage, between singular and plural.

Comment: Ah! You may have hit on something there! In the *singular* version, it's perfectly natural to use Saxon genitive ***'s***, which *can in fact be heard*. But of course there's no way of detecting that in the spoken plural version. And even in the *written* version, it would just be a bare ***'s*** after ***hours*** (and you gotta admit it would take an *incredibly* pernickety pedant to write ***We have two hours' free study time on Friday afternoons*** if they even gave that parsing a look-in! :)